# rails: filter categories where there are at least one article

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have articles and categories in a n:m relation:

I looking for a find statement on the Category Model so that I can get all categories witch consist at least one article.

Should be easy, but I didn't find a efficient solution, without searching retrieving all the articles.

Thanks,
Maechi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that counter cache is your friend here. Take a look [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column).

You can add the counter cache to the `categories` table and in the CategoryArticles you do like

```
class CategoryArticles
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :category, :counter_cache => true
end
```

So you can find your Category with

```
@categories = Category.find(:all, :conditions => ["category_articles_count > ?", 0])
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed! Do you know how I do it when I don't have the CategoryArticles Model by just implementing the has_and_belongs_to_many property?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do it with a `has_and_belong_to_many`. My suggestion is to do it like that.

    class CategoryArticles
      belongs_to :article
      belongs_to :category, :counter_cache => true
    end
    
    class Category
      has_many :articles, :through => :category_articles
      has_many :category_articles
    end

    class Article
      has_many :categories, :through => :category_articles
      has_many :category_articles
    end

Comment: Just saw that you cannot format the code in comments... you can take a look in this gist http://gist.github.com/611736